# Storing files in a git repo that have to be owned by root in a docker container

Tags: docker

I have a Dockerfile that extends [Atmoz/sftp](https://hub.docker.com/r/atmoz/sftp/). It is stored in a git repo. The purpose of the image is to be loaded from `docker-compose` and serve as the test version of a business partners SFTP server that the main application in the git repo can connect to and perform sftp operations.

I want to persist the ssh server keys in the repo that lives in /etc/ssh. Like the readme recommends. I do the following in docker-compose:

```
volumes:
    - ./provision/sftp/etc/ssh_host_rsa_key:/etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
    - ./provision/sftp/etc/ssh_host_rsa_key.pub:/etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key.pub
```

Those files need to be owned by root and set to 0700. Git can store the chmod bits of files just fine, but I need docker to make those files owned by root inside the container, and still owned by my local user on my host.

How do I accomplish this?